# how to predict online tensorflow model using JS

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow-serving, gcp-ai-platform-training

We build a NN model in tensorflow similar to 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/tf-keras

Then we exported it to GCP using the following `gcloud ai-platform models create` commands
and predict using `gcloud ai-platform predict` works fine

Now we want to do online prediction using javascript, seems to have several options:

1. using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/automl, but 
   Checking https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/automl/latest/v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient.html#predict 
   it seems that it can not be used for neural networks(?)
   When we run the example code 
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/automl
   with our parameters we get 'Invalid resource ID' error
2. Using REST API, curl works fine but how do we set permanent authorization in the server ?
3. Any other suggestion ?

Amir

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by building Python container that run on gcloud
(https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy)

The JS call the container using REST API, the python container do the prediction and reply to results the JS